# Rasterio fails to create new tiff file inside for loop

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, directory

I'm trying to save rasters with rasterio inside for loop.
For reason that I don't understand, the for loop works only in the first loop (being able to save the tiff image) but then when comes to the 2nd iteration it fails due to RasterioIOError:

> RasterioIOError: Attempt to create new tiff file
> 'result/imgs/K/K.tiff' failed: No such file or
> directory

This is my code:

```
loc_raster='result/imgs/'
for shape in shapes:
    #extract the name of the raster
    test_name = re.search(r'/(.*?)-', shape).group(1)
    element=test_name.split('/')[2]
........do things.................................
    raster_name=element+'/'+element+'.tiff'


    savedir = pathlib.Path(loc_raster)
    #create the dir, including nested dirs and don't complain if it is already there
    savedir.mkdir(parents=True,exist_ok=True)    
    
    #get crs as wkt
    from rasterio.crs import CRS

    rasterCrs = CRS.from_epsg(4326)
    rasterCrs.data
    {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

    #definition, register and close of interpolated raster
    triInterpRaster = rasterio.open(savedir/raster_name,
                                    'w',
                                    driver='GTiff',
                                    height=bbox_size[1],
                                    width=bbox_size[0],
                                    count=1,
                                    dtype=field.dtype,
                                    crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'},
                                    transform=transf,
                                    )
    triInterpRaster.write(field,1)
    triInterpRaster.close()
```

That works and saves the first raster in the correct folder, but then in the 2nd iteration, when the raster name is K I get the following error:

> RasterioIOError: Attempt to create new tiff file
> 'kriging_result/group1/imgs/K/K.tiff' failed: No such file or
> directory

I don't know what is the reason for this as it seems to be the right directory, so I can't understand why is this happen. Maybe is becase it's only one letter, K?

**My end goal is to be able to save the images in the following iterations after the first.**

Comment: It's possibly due to the ``savedir/raster_name`` expression in your ``rasterio.open`` command. Writen as his (ie. without quotes) python sould be raise a TypeError. If it's the error the expression ``"""f{savedir}/{raster_name}"""`` sould work (on python >= 3.6).

Comment: @Atm since `savedir` is a pathlib `Path` object it should work just like Reut has it

Comment: I think your issue is this: `raster_name = element+'/'+element+'.tiff'`. You are not creating the folder `element` in your `mkdir()` call, so when trying to save, the folder K exists but not the second folder K inside that folder.

Comment: @JonasV Oh yes, I hadn't noticed, thanks.

Comment: @JonasV was right, that was the issue. please consider write your comment as answer so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is this: `raster_name = element+'/'+element+'.tiff'`. You are not creating the folder `element` in your `mkdir()` call, so when trying to save, the folder K exists but not the second folder K inside that folder.